# Doing crunches for month and after that stop doing it effect body shape?

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, bodyweight-exercises, flexibility, physique

I've done crunches for one month regularly in the gym and after that I stopped exercising. And my stomach came out after two months. So is it because I stop doing crunches ?
What should I do in order to maintain the same abdomen structure?

Comment: Edited your question, feel free to revert it

Comment: No. Crunches do nothing in terms of belly fat. Spot fat reduction is a myth. To reduce fat you need to be in a calorie deficit. You need exercise + nutrition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the crunches themselves have very little to do with the overall bulging of your stomach. That would be called spot reducing, which does not exist. The fact that your stomach came back is due to the fact that you stopped going to the gym and exercising. You want to be at a caloric deficit to be able to lose body fat.

Answer (score 1):

yeh, you can't spot reduce its a myth, the first place you gain fat will be the last place u lose it,but targeting certain areas does compress the fat thus making it look slimmer or flatter so yeh if your going to the gym but not doing crèches and your stomach seems noticeably larger it is because your not doing crunches